# Need to get only Hostname not FQDN in java

Tags: java, hostname, fqdn

I have multiple applications, hosted on different servers.
All applications use java 8.
I tried java.net function InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() to get hostname, it's giving inconsistent result for different servers.
For some servers, I am getting hostname without domain name and for some FQDN.
I want consistent result for all applications with same code.
I want to keep string truncation as a last option.
If some function is available in java to get only hostname(without domain name), i would like to use function to get consistent result in all applications.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can try InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() or InetAddress.getName() methods. Assuming there is a proper name service running on your net these two should do the trick.

The JavaDocs for [getCanonicalHostName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getCanonicalHostName()) says

Gets the fully qualified domain name for this IP address. Best effort method, meaning we may not be able to return the FQDN depending on the underlying system configuration.

So if you want to get your local FQDN, you can typically call: `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName()`

Comment: I need only hostname, not FQDN.. I need to get only hostname without domain name.